# Study the series $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\cos{\left(\frac{n+2}{n^2+4}\right)}$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, solution-verification

I have to study the convergence of the following series:
$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\cos{\left(\frac{n+2}{n^2+4}\right)}$$
I have thought to apply the asymptotic criterion.
I know that $\cos{\left(\frac{n+2}{n^2+4}\right)}\sim 1-\left(\frac{n+2}{n^2+4}\right)^2\cdot \frac{1}{2}$. 
Then it is right to say that since:
$$1-\left(\frac{n+2}{n^2+4}\right)^2\cdot \frac{1}{2}\sim -\frac{1}{2n^2}\,\,\ (*)$$ then the original series converges?

**I am not sure it is possible to"concatenate" the asymptotic equivalence as I have done in (*)**

**$\color{red}{Note:}$** by $a_n\sim b_n$ I intend that the $\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{a_n}{b_n}=1$

Comment: That is too much work for this problem. What is the limit of the sequence being summed?

Comment: The terms approach $1$, so it definitely diverges.

Comment: I have no idea where (*) comes from, but it's definitely wrong. For example, as $n\to\infty$ the LHS tends to $1$ while the RHS tends to $0$.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A necessary condition for convergence is that the general term tends to zero. However $$\frac{n+2}{n^2+4}=\frac{1/n+2/n^2}{1+4/n^2}\to0$$ and therefore $$\cos\left(\frac{n+2}{n^2+4}\right)\to1$$